# Maximum path sum for Mario in 2-d maze

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem which goes something like this...

Mario is stuck in a 2d maze (M*N array). He is currently on the first row (any cell). He is restricted to 3 types of movements - down, left and right. Each cell has a fruit (with +ve or -ve value). A fruit is consumed when Mario passes through a cell and accordingly the points obtained either increase or decrease after which the fruit ceases to exist. The aim is to find the maximum points for Mario by getting him to the last row.

So I have boiled down the problem to the following ...

A 2d array of dimensions M*N is available. Each cell has either a +ve or -ve value. We can either move down, left or right, but in doing so we nullify the current cell(make it 0). We have to find the maximum sum possible for traversal from the first row to the last row.

The method I designed :

```
int maxVal(int[][] mat)
    {
        int r = mat.length;
        int c = mat[0].length;
        int[][] maxValues = new int[r][c];
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    maxValues[i][j] = mat[i][j];
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (i == 0) {
                    maxValues[i][j] = maxValues[i][j - 1] + mat[i][j];
                    maxValues[i][j - 1] = 0;
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    maxValues[i][j] = maxValues[i - 1][j] + mat[i][j];
                    maxValues[i - 1][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    int temp = Math.max(maxValues[i][j - 1], maxValues[i - 1][j]);
                    if (j + 1 < c) {
                        temp = Math.max(temp, maxValues[i][j + 1]);
                        if (maxValues[i][j + 1] >= maxValues[i][j - 1]
                                && maxValues[i][j + 1] >= maxValues[i - 1][j]) {
                            maxValues[i][j + 1]=0;
                        }
                        else if (maxValues[i][j - 1] >= maxValues[i][j + 1]
                                && maxValues[i][j - 1] >= maxValues[i - 1][j]) {
                            maxValues[i][j - 1]=0;
                        }
                        else if (maxValues[i-1][j ] >= maxValues[i][j - 1]
                                && maxValues[i-1][j] >= maxValues[i][j+1]) {
                            maxValues[i-1][j]=0;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(maxValues[i-1][j ] >= maxValues[i][j - 1])
                            maxValues[i-1][j]=0;
                        else if(maxValues[i][j-1 ] >= maxValues[i-1][j ])
                            maxValues[i][j-1]=0;
                    }

                    temp += mat[i][j];
                    maxValues[i][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxValues[r - 1][c - 1];
    }
```

I would like feedback as to what I am doing wrong as I am clearly overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your approach. Your goal is to examine all possible paths, then choose the one with highest value. I suggest using a recursion approach.

Comment: Perhaps you are suggesting a recursive approach where I should call the method itself with the existing array but with the current cell nullified. I have considered this but it seems a bit too complex to convert to a DP solution. Apologies if I sound naive here.. I have just started exploring DP problems

Comment: The problem is designed such that Mario cannot visit the same cell twice and get the same point delta. It is an open question whether or not Mario can visit the same cell twice in a row (left, left, right, right, right). That determines path possibilities, but it still boils down to the basic logic: find all possible paths Mario could traverse. Pick the one with highest value.